# How to use initial useState value on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm working with react hooks, and when page is loaded I've set some default / initial values that are related to some kind of sorting, and it looks like this:

```
 const [sortingOptions, setSortingOptions] = useState({
    name: 'productName',
    direction: 'ASC',
  });
```

Let's say app is used and ofcourse this values have changed, and let's say I would like to get to this values again on click.. for example:

```
const resetSorts => {
   // could I call something here to setSortingOptions again to productName and asc ? 
};
```

On first I thought about creating new variable, for example :

```
 const initialSortState = {
    name: 'productName',
    direction: 'ASC',
  };
```

and setting it like this:

```
setSortingOptions(initialSortState );
```

But I'm not sure if this is right approach, and is there another way to back to INITIAL / DEFAULT state value on click?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: It seems just fine. You can also use this variable to initialize your state. You don't need any other complex logic here I think. Do it simple as this. One thing though, just check @ahota's answer. If your initial state depends on some heavy process you can consider doing a lazy initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set it to the default, you're going to need to store the default in a variable somewhere. So your approach is correct, as well as quite readable. From looking at the docs, if you have a more complicated component, could [provide a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) that returns the default value, but for your use case, I would say just use a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no build-in functionality to get back to initial state.

Your approach seems fine. What we could also do is to prepare a proper function for this case.

```
function resetSorts() {
  setSortingOptions({
    name: 'productName',
    direction: 'ASC',
  });
};
```

Later you can call it in any place you want:

```
resetSorts();
```

Or if your're willing to do it on click:

```
<Button onClick={resetSorts} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You can call a function onClick.

```
const resetSorts = () => {
  setSortingOptions({
    name: 'productName',
    direction: 'ASC',
    });
}
```

Now you can call this function onClick to get back to your desired initial state.

```
<button onClick={resetSorts}>Get to initial state</button>
```